# SwiftUI - Using a Button to toggle "Favoriting" a dynamic item

Tags: swiftui, userdefaults

I'm new to SwiftUI and data management. As stated above, I'm trying to use a button that will allow users to toggle favoriting an item they are viewing. I'm trying to write that value to the UserDefaults.

I've managed to hack together a version of this where the button successfully writes and removes the object, but the issue is that it doesn't toggle the view. The button only updates when you navigate back to the item again after leaving the view. Below is the code I currently have. My wish is to visually toggle the button as the user favorites or un-favorites an item.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemDetail: View {
var productID: Int
var productTitle: String
var itemURL: String
var productDescription: String
var productPrice: Double
var venueTitle: String
var newStatus: Bool
var diningPlan: Bool
var kidFriendly: Bool
var vegetarian: Bool
var glutenFree: Bool
var featuredProduct: Bool
var containsAlcohol: Bool

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            LoadableImageView(with: self.itemURL)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .cornerRadius(6)
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                Text(self.productTitle)
                    .font(.system(size: 22))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Spacer()
                Text("$\(self.productPrice, specifier: "%.2f")")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.leading, 50)
            }
            HStack {
                Text(self.productDescription)
                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                    .foregroundColor(Color("bodyText"))
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 1.5, alignment: .leading)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.top, 5)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 8) {
                    if(self.newStatus) {
                        Image("tag-new")
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                    }
                    if(self.diningPlan) {
                        Image("tag-ddp")
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                    }
                    if(self.kidFriendly) {
                        Image("tag-kidfriendly")
                            .renderingMode(.original)

                    }
                    if(self.vegetarian) {
                        Image("tag-vegetarian")
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                    }
                    if(self.glutenFree) {
                        Image("tag-gluten")
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                    }
                    if(self.featuredProduct) {
                        Image("tag-featured")
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                    }
                    if(self.containsAlcohol) {
                        Image("tag-alcohol")
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                    }
                }.padding(.top, 5)
                HStack {
                    Text("Located At:")
                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Text(self.venueTitle)
                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                        .foregroundColor(Color("bodyText"))
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.top, 50)
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: self.productTitle) != nil {
                    Button(action: {
                        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: self.productTitle)
                        print("Unfavorited \(self.productTitle)")
                        self.isFavorite = ""
                        print("\(self.isFavorite)")
                    }) {
                        Text("Favorite")
                            .padding()
                    }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 50)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                } else {
                    Button(action: {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set("Favorite", forKey: self.productTitle)
                        print("Added Favorite \(self.productTitle)")
                        self.isFavorite = "Favorite"
                        print("\(self.isFavorite)")
                    }) {
                        Text("Add to Favorites")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 50)
                            .overlay (
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                    .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }.padding(.bottom)
        }.padding(.all)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Item Details"))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`isFavorite` should be something that SwiftUI can observe for changes. for example it could be:

```
@State var isFavorite = false
```

or

```
@Binding var isFavorite: Bool
```

For your case it's better to use `Combine` and build a `ViewModel`that contains all information about the item. Then you should publish changes in the model and any `View` observing for that changes will refresh automatically.

[This search result](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=ACYBGNSyPsotG5OEJRRRwDurxldY6KCdcg%3A1575565777186&ei=0TnpXfbxCpOx8gLmtoK4Cw&q=swiftui+combine+tutorial&oq=swiftui+combine+tutorial&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13j0i7i30l2j0i8i7i30.10233.11424..11565...0.3..0.276.1362.0j1j5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.ZQgAuKC0718&ved=0ahUKEwi2nuDz_57mAhWTmFwKHWabALcQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) may help you to understand more about the `Combine` and `SwiftUI`.

<sub>And note that UserDefaults is not a good place to store these kind of data</sub>